# Why doesn't an update SQL statement cause history list length to grow in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to understand why an update statement does not cause the history list length (HLL) to grow when the DB has high write load. Select statement causes the HLL to grow in the same scenario though.

**Scenario 1: HLL is not growing**

1. MySQL DB has 1 table with 2 columns (1 primary key)
2. Using sysbench to run update and insert statements into this table with 8 threads
3. Simultaneously with sysbench load, having a long running transaction:

```
> START TRANSACTION;
> UPDATE t1 SET c2 = 'val' WHERE c1 != 'DONE'.
[leaving this terminal open without committing]
```

**Scenario 2: HLL is growing (as expected)**

1. Same set up as above: 1 table and sysbench running write statements against the table.
2. Simultaneously with sysbench load, the long running transaction is only a SELECT statement:

```
> START TRANSACTION;
> SELECT * from t1 WHERE c1 != 'DONE'.
[leaving this terminal open without committing]
```

**Expectation**:
The HLL should grow rapidly in both scenarios since both scenarios should use a read view.

**Actual Observation**:
HLL grows rapidly only in Scenario 2. For scenario 1, the HLL remains almost constant.

**Question:**
Why is this behaviour? Why doesn't an update statement with where condition doesn't cause HLL to grow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-consistent-read.html makes the following statements:

> A consistent read means that InnoDB uses multi-versioning to present to a query a snapshot of the database at a point in time.

> If the transaction isolation level is `REPEATABLE READ` (the default level), all consistent reads within the same transaction read the snapshot established by the first such read in that transaction.

> Consistent read is the default mode in which InnoDB processes `SELECT` statements in `READ COMMITTED` and `REPEATABLE READ` isolation levels. A consistent read does not set any locks on the tables it accesses

The wording suggests that actions other than consistent read do not establish a snapshot.

You can observe that `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, and also locking reads such as `SELECT...FOR UPDATE` are applied to the most recent committed version of a row, as if the transaction used the `READ COMMITTED` isolation level.

So these are not consistent reads, and based on the statements from the documentation above, they do not establish a snapshot.